# Rails calculate average across belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Purchase model, which belongs to both a product and a model. I am trying to keep an average price of all the purchases a user makes, and update this average whenever a new purchase is saved.

I know that I could just calculate a rolling average, but I am trying to do this using the average method provided by ActiveRecord. One other caveat is that in this contrived example, it is valid for price to be nil for a Product. Will average just ignore all instances of nil when calculating the average?

My main hang up is with the `after_save` block in Purchases.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    #price   :float

    has_many :purchases
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    #average_purchase_price  :float

    has_many :purchases
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :product

    after_save do
       #Cant quite nail down the syntax here.
       user.update_attributes average_purchase_price: user.purchases.average(#todo average purchase prices)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The query that is generated is SELECT AVG(average_purchase_price) FROM purchases...
(refer to this: http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M000293).

If you look up mysql's documentation on group functions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html) it states that null values are ignored unless explicitly specified. So yes, nil values will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I figured. Any suggestions for syntax on my after_save block for updating this average?

Comment: user.update_attribute(:average_purchase_price, user.purchases.average(:price)), i.e. if you don't want validations. Otherwise use update_attributes. Furthermore if you aren't updating a purchases price anywhere in your application (i.e. after the purchase has been created), you can change after_save to after_create, since the later will only run once, while the former will run every time you update a purchase. Depends on your requirements.

Comment: I don't think this syntax will work, since :price is a property of products, not purchases. I basically need to be able to do something like user.update_attribute(:average_purchase_price, user.purchases.average(:purchase.product.price)), though I know that isn't valid either.

Comment: Oh sorry. If you want to use the average function, than you'll need to join the two tables, and then call average(:price) on it. I'm not sure on the syntax, but it would look something like this: Product.joins(:purchases => :users).where(:users => {:user_id => self.user.id}).average(:price). I hope this works.

Comment: Hmm, this syntax doesn't seem to work. I will see if I can figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Ok, here is what I think works: Purchase.joins([:user, :product]).where(:users => {:id => self.user} ).average(:price)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
user.update_attribute(:average_purchase_price, 
  user.purchases.average("products.price", :joins => :product)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because :price is a property of products, not purchases.

Comment: Updated the answer take a look.